# Check if a date is equal to other date using Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, date, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am trying  to check if one date is equal than the other date, but I can't get the match because the date format coming from the form turns into a different order once it gets through the "parse" code.
I need to format this date to find the match, here is a sample code to show how I am trying:

```
 ...

 // $ago will give me this date: 2016-12-09 00:00:00
 $ago = Carbon\Carbon::today()->addDays(2); // Todays date + 2 days

 //$request->datex has the date coming from a form with this format, '12-06-2016'.

 // Once a parse $request->datex here, the date gets out of order:
 $my_date = Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->datex);
 // it shows the date like this, 2016-09-12 00:00:00 , I need it to be on this format: 2016-12-09 00:00:00

 // then I could do this:

 if ( $ago$ == $my_date ) {

  dd($my_date.' is equal to: '.$ago );

 }else{

  dd(' Not equal!');

 }
 ...
```

Thanks for looking!

Comment: That's the issue with date time, when you have a date like `2016-09-12` is that it can be treated as either `Sept 12, 2016` or `Dec 9, 2016`. So Piotr is correct that you need to specify the expected format during initialization, or else parse will treat it one way, which may or may not be the way you're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
$my_date = Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->datex);
```

with this:

```
$my_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $request->datex)
```

I've assumed that your format `'12-06-2016'` means `DAY-MONTH-YEAR`

**UPDATE**
Tested my solution on my machine and it works, date is recognized properly:
When

```
$request->datex = '12-06-2016'
```

then

```
$my_date = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $datex);
```

gives me date like that: `public 'date' => string '2016-12-06 18:52:09.000000' (length=26)`

Date has been parsed properly. The thing that I've assumed just now. These dates won't be same cause of hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds. To fix that just we have to compare dates that way:

```
if ( $ago->format('Y-m-d') == $my_date->format('Y-m-d') )
    //do something awesome with our equal dates
```

Comment: Probably a better solution than mine.

Comment: This gives me an error - "The separation symbol could not be found Trailing data".

Comment: Yes I did add the semi-colon, I've tried that before as well without success.

Comment: extend your question with info what your `$request->datex` contains

Comment: Run `var_dump($request->datex)`, your date must not match the m-d-Y format exactly.

Comment: I did in my question above: "//$request->datex has the date coming from a form with this format, '12-06-2016'."

Answer (score 0):

PHP expects DD-MM-YYYY or MM/DD/YYYY formats.

If you always have a MM-DD-YYYY format, you could do this before parsing:

```
$request->datex = str_replace('-', '/', $request->datex);
```

Comment: I am expecting to convert this date format: '12-06-2016'. Into this format: 2016-12-06 00:00:00

Comment: Like I said here, 12-06-2016 is interpreted as June 12th, not December 6th in PHP since you're using hyphens instead of slashes.  Either specify the format or replace the hyphens.